# issue while creating go build for Mac from linux?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, go

I am trying to create a build for Mac from linux machine. I am able to do this by below common without enabling CGO.

```
env GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

Using CGO enabled command

```
env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

But if I enable CGO then it does not work and get below error

```
# os/user
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/getgrouplist_darwin.go: In function 'mygetgrouplist':
/usr/local/go/src/os/user/getgrouplist_darwin.go:16:11: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getgrouplist' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int rv = getgrouplist(user, (int) group, buf, ngroups);
           ^
# net
/usr/local/go/src/net/cgo_bsd.go:15:72: could not determine kind of name for C.AI_MASK
# ConfigTool/Go/vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
/tmp/go-build769992187/b129/_x011.o: In function `unixDlError':
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3-binding.c:38475: undefined reference to `dlerror'
/tmp/go-build769992187/b129/_x011.o: In function `unixDlClose':
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3-binding.c:38506: undefined reference to `dlclose'
/tmp/go-build769992187/b129/_x011.o: In function `unixDlSym':
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3-binding.c:38502: undefined reference to `dlsym'
/tmp/go-build769992187/b129/_x011.o: In function `unixDlOpen':
vendor/github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3-binding.c:38461: undefined reference to `dlopen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I ran into this issue because my go code was using Sqlite3. For a sqlite supported build to run CGO_ENABLED should not be zero. I did not find the solution to this problem but I created a separated build for Mac only & that build is running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to cross-compile for `darwin` on `linux` and you're using `CGO_ENABLED=1`, then you'll need a `C` cross compiler also.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22510#issuecomment-340938955

Comment: Can you educate on what is the C cross compiler here for compiling binaries targeted for Mac from Alpine ?